# Adding different icons to each cells in table view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I want to add different icons to the table view present in my app.Can anyone guide me through a proper array or if possible show some sample code or example.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Christy

Comment: you want to show one icon per row of tableview ?

Comment: can you explain a bit more. do you want to give each 'cell' a different icon?

Comment: are the icons images if images then create an array and add images in that array and use that array.

Comment: check this link <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html>

Comment: @Aman -Yes i want to add one icon pre row of table view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Say the icons are stored as icon0.png, icon1.png and so on in the app bundle.
You can give the icon for each cell as

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:    
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%d.png",indexPath.row]];
```

**Swift**

```
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "icon\(indexPath.row).png")
```

Comment: Is there any specific size for the icon to be used.

Comment: ya you should resize all icons to same size. i think 50x50 is enough

Comment: thanks a lot for the help,32x32is enough ,thanks a lot friend

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have an array somewhere to return the correct number in `numberOfRowsInSection`. That array is the one you use to fill up the cells. If you only want to display icons in your cells, your array of icons is like that.

So, for example:

```
UIImage *one = ...;
UIImage *two = ...;
[arrayIcons addObject: one];
[arrayIcons addObject: two];
```

and in numberOfRowsInSection, return `[arrayIcons count]`.

In the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you have the variable `indexPath`. If you want to know which cell you have, you use: `indexPath.row`.

So, if you load the cell (probably custom, see other answers), which has a `UIImageView` (say it's named: imageView), and you load the icons in the cells like this:

```
cell.imageView = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[arrayIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You wil have to define custom cells for your UITableView.

[This tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) is what you are looking for.